# How do I convert some computed values (floating point) to the RGB type in Julia?

Tags: image-processing, colors, casting, julia

I am attempting an image convolution using a 3x3 kernel_test and am running into a challenge with returning the correct type so I can view an image back (after the convolution). My code is as below.

```
begin
    function update_mat_val(org_clr::AbstractRGB, new_clr::AbstractRGB, n::Number)
        r = reinterpret(N0f8, (red(org_clr) + (red(new_clr) * n)))
        g = reinterpret(N0f8, (green(org_clr) + (green(new_clr) * n)))
        b = reinterpret(N0f8, (blue(org_clr) + (blue(new_clr) * n)))
        
        return RGB(r, g, b)
    end
end
```

```
function convolve_image(M::AbstractMatrix, K::AbstractMatrix)
    #M is the matrix, K is the kernel
    
    (m_height, m_width) = size(M)
    (k_height, k_width) = size(K)
    
    conv_mk = zeros(typeof(M[1,1]), m_height+k_height-1, m_width+k_width-1)
    (conv_height, conv_width) = size(conv_mk)
    
    for i in 1:m_height, j in 1:m_width
        for p in 1:k_height, q in 1:k_width
            conv_mk[i+p-1,j+q-1] = update_mat_val(conv_mk[i+p-1,j+q-1], M[i,j], K[p,q])
        end
    end
    
    return conv_mk
end
```

```
convolve_image(image, kernel_test)
```

Initially, I did not use the reinterpret method and the values were falling outside the 0-255 values that the RGB can hold. So after reading up a little online, I tried to use reinterpret. The error before I attempted to reinterpret and after are given in corresponding order below. How do I correctly process the values so I get an image back?

```
ArgumentError: element type FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8} is an 8-bit type representing 256 values from 0.0 to 1.0,

but the values (0.9254901960784314, 0.9686274509803922, 1.0019607843137255) do not lie within this range.

See the READMEs for FixedPointNumbers and ColorTypes for more information.

throw_colorerror_(::Type{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}}, ::Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64})@types.jl:686
throw_colorerror(::Type{ColorTypes.RGB{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}}}, ::Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64})@types.jl:736
checkval@types.jl:654[inlined]
RGB@types.jl:101[inlined]
_convert@conversions.jl:87[inlined]
cconvert@conversions.jl:76[inlined]
convert@conversions.jl:73[inlined]
setindex!@array.jl:849[inlined]
convolve_image(::Array{ColorTypes.RGB{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2}, ::Array{Float64,2})@Other: 12
top-level scope@Local: 1
```

```
bitcast: target type not a leaf primitive type

reinterpret@essentials.jl:414[inlined]
update_mat_val@Other: 3[inlined]
convolve_image(::Array{ColorTypes.RGB{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2}, ::Array{Float64,2})@Other: 12
top-level scope@Local: 1
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try to simplify your question to something like "how to covert data type A to a data type B"?

Comment: Thank you. I have simplified the question. I have also attempted different variants of the reinterpret with different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your update function like this

```
update_mat_val(val1::AbstractRGB, val2::AbstractRGB, n::Number) = val1 + val2 * n
```

No need for all the conversions all over the place.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work in all cases. Depends on what happens inside the computation. If the value exceeds 1.0, this fails. Also, if it did work, a separate method call would be unnecessary, could just write it out in the convolution method, itself. But that didn't work. :)

Comment: Does it really fail, though? In my tests, if value goes above 1.0, the color saturates, giving the same effect as `clamp`. As for your other point, that's hardly something to complain about, right? Anyway, the whole point of the RGB types is to simplify these computations, not complicate them, by making you jump through all these hoops.

Comment: Thank you! I went back and reviewed this all over again and found it just worked? But if I write it slightly differently, it doesn't. So if you write the function as in your answer, it works just fine but if you write it in the format: function(a,b,n) return a + b * n, that fails. Also, in the convolution function itself, if I write it as x += y * n, it fails, but x = x + y * n works. But this solved a lot of unnecesssary code and taught me something new, so thanks again.

Comment: Hm.. Those failures are very strange. Those cases should all be identical. Are you certain there aren't any typos or something?

Comment: I'm going to say this is certainly a weird experience. But the code works on and off and I cannot seem to explain why. I have now rewritten the code so I can always pass in Offset Arrays (as the previous version wasn't working as intended - errors at the edge of the image, etc). But this version is facing the same clamping issues as well.

Comment: Am adding a new answer to provide formatted code and details.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I managed to figure out the issue.

In particular cases, the convolution results in an r, g or b value > 1.0. That representation cannot work.

My current solution is to limit the convolution to 1.0 (if it exceeds). I am not currently solving for values < 0.0 but that is trivial.

```
function update_mat_val(org_clr::AbstractRGB, new_clr::AbstractRGB, n::Number)
    r = red(org_clr) + (red(new_clr) * n)
    g = green(org_clr) + (green(new_clr) * n)
    b = blue(org_clr) + (blue(new_clr) * n)
        
    if r > 1.0
        r = 1.0
    end
    
    if g > 1.0
        g = 1.0
    end
    
    if b > 1.0
        b = 1.0
    end
                
    return RGB(r, g, b)
end
```

Comment: Base also has a `clamp` function, so instead of all the `if` statements, you could also write `r, g, b = clamp.((r, g, b), 0, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks! TIL. I'll apply that.

Comment: Tried clamp and that too didn't broadcast across the values of the colour, failing on an isless method match. But clamping the individual R,G&B values and then returning them worked so I could get rid of the if-else block.

Answer (score 0):

This issue keeps recurring with other variants of the code as well. I continue to get errors of the following kind with the code below.

**Error Type 1**

```
ArgumentError: element type FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8} is an 8-bit type representing 256 values from 0.0 to 1.0,

but the values (0.9602378709470972, 0.992399754308552, 1.018129260997716) do not lie within this range.
```

**Error Type 2**

```
ArgumentError: element type FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8} is an 8-bit type representing 256 values from 0.0 to 1.0,

but the values (-0.006372549019607852, -0.0034313725490196026, -0.004411764705882355) do not lie within this range.
```

**Code**

```
function extend_mat(M::AbstractMatrix, i, j)
    (h,w) = size(M)
    return M[clamp(i, 1, h), clamp(j, 1, w)]
end
```

```
function convolve(M::AbstractMatrix, K::AbstractMatrix)
    #M is the matrix, K is the kernel
    
    (mh, mw) = size(M)
    (kh, kw) = size(K)
    
    half_kh = kh ÷ 2
    half_kw = kw ÷ 2
    
    conv_mk = similar(M)
    
    @inbounds for i in 1:mh, j in 1:mw
        accumulator = 0 * M[1, 1]
        for p in -half_kh:-half_kh + kh - 1, q in -half_kw:-half_kw + kw - 1
            accumulator += extend_mat(M, i-p, j-q) * K[p,q]
        end
        conv_mk[i, j] = accumulator
    end
    
    return conv_mk
end
```

```
function sobel_edge_detect(image, dim = 1)
    sx, sy = Kernel.sobel()
    if dim == 1
        return convolve(image, sx)
    elseif dim == 2
        return convolve(image, sy)
    else
        return convolve(image, sx)
    end
end
```

```
sobel_edge_detect(philip)
```

Comment: I have a suspicion about what's going on. `conv_mk` contains values of type `RGBA{Normed{UInt8,8}`. When you multiply them with a number, for example an `Int`, the product type is `RGBA{Float32}`, which can go outside the range 0..1. When you assign it back into `conv_mk`, an attempt is made to convert back to `RGBA{Normed{UInt8,8}`. This succeeds when the numbers are in 0..1, but fails when it falls outside. The conclusion is that you should allow `conv_mk` to hold a 'wider' type, for example `typeof(first(img)*first(K))`.

Comment: I agree with @DNF. If you use a "wider" datatype for `conv_mk` this should work.